# How to call a Swift function with a callback from C

Tags: ios, c, swift, objective-c

I am trying to write an iOS plugin for Unity, which requires the use of a bridge with a C layer.

The plugin itself is written in Swift.

Currently my implementation works like so:

// Swift

```
@objc public class SomeClass  {

    @objc public func SomeFunction() -> String {
        return "Hello"
    }

}
```

// C

```
extern "C" {

    void _someFunction() {
        // I can access the Swift file using "[SomeClass shared]"
        // This returns the "Hello" string correctly
        NSString *helloMessage = [[SomeClass shared] SomeFunction];
    }

}
```

This works, but now I need to make an async call which requires a callback from the Swift implementation.

// Swift

```
@objc public class SomeClass  {

    @objc public func SomeFunction(completionHandler: (String) -> Void) {
        // Gets called after some async operations
        completionHandler(“hello”)
    }

}
```

Is it possible to call this Swift function from the C layer and how would you do so?

// C

```
extern "C" {

    void _someFunction() {
        // ??????
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up bridging well then the call should be like

```
void _someFunction() {
    [[SomeClass shared] SomeFunctionWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString * _Nonnull value) {
        NSLog(@"Result: %@", value);
    }];
}
```

Btw, classes to be visible in Objective-C should be 'is-a' `NSObject`, like

```
@objcMembers public class SomeClass: NSObject  {

    public static var shared = SomeClass()

    public func SomeFunction() -> String {
        return "Hello"
    }

    public func SomeFunction(completionHandler: (String) -> Void) {
        // Gets called after some async operations
        completionHandler("hello")
    }

}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have tried this implementation, but it throws an error "No visible @interface for ’SomeClass’ declares the selector ‘SomeFunction:’". Even though it could find the function I had previously without the 'completionHandler'.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't write the 'WithCompletionHandler' part. Best use the Xcode autocomplete!